# Defining topology on projective space via topology of a field

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, projective-space

Given a topology on a field $K$ (in my case a non-archimedean local field with valuation $\nu$ and ring of integers $R$ with maximal Ideal $\mathfrak{m}$), the goal is to define a topology on $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ that comes from $K$. I know that one way to do this is to look at the map
\begin{align}
K^{n+1} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace &\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n(K) \\
(x_0, \dots, x_n) &\longmapsto [x_0, \dots,x_n]
\end{align}
which is surjective, so we can define the topology on the target to be the quotient topology from $K^{n+1}$. (The topology there being understood as product topology).

My question is the following: Since we know that $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ admits an open cover by $n+1$ copies of $K^n$, is there a way to define a topology via this covering? Would this give us the same topology as the quotient?

Another question is, when we want to check the continuity of the specialization map
\begin{align}
\text{Sp }\colon \mathbb{P}^n(K) &\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n(k) \\
[x_0, \dots x_n] &\longmapsto [\lambda x_0 \text{ mod } \mathfrak{m}, \dots, \lambda x_0 \text{ mod } \mathfrak{m}]
\end{align}
where $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$ and $\lambda$ scales the coordinates so that all are in $R$ (but not all in $\mathfrak{m}$), with $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ having discrete topology and $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ the avove, can we check this using an open cover of $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ by copies of $R^n$? In that case, the continuity of reduction mod $\mathfrak{m}$ is obvious via the metric on each space. For clarification: $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ does admit an open cover by $n+1$ copies of $\mathbb{A}^n(R)=R^n$, because coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ can be scaled so that all of them are in the ring of integers R. This works for any local field, but thinking specifically of $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$, $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$ or even $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}$ should help intuition.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking in your second question.  You can check continuity of any map on any topological space by checking it on an open cover of the space, since continuity is a local property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: you can define a topology on $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ by saying a subset is open iff its intersection with each of the copies of $K^n$ is open in the product topology of $K^n$.  Or equivalently, we can take as a basis for our topology all the open subsets of any of the copies of $K^n$ that cover $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$.

This topology is in fact the same as the quotient topology.  To prove this, let $U_i\subset K^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ be the set of points whose $i$th coordinate is nonzero.  Each $U_i$ is open and saturated with respect to the quotient map $p:K^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{P}^n(K)$, so each $p(U_i)$ is open with respect to the quotient topology, and $p$ restricts to a quotient map $U_i\to p(U_i)$.  So, all we need to show is that the quotient topology on each $p(U_i)$ the the same as the product topology on $K^n$ when we identify them in the usual way.

For convenience of notation, we show this in the case $i=0$.  To show the quotient topology on $p(U_0)$ is the same as product topology on $K^n$, we need to show the map $q:U_0\to K^n$ given by $q(x_0,\dots,x_n)=(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0)$ is a quotient map.  Now note that the map $f:U_0\to U_0$ defined by $f(x_0,\dots,x_n)=(x_0,x_1x_0,\dots,x_nx_0)$ is a homeomorphism, and $qf$ is just the projection that drops the first coordinate.  This projection is a quotient map, and thus so is $q$.